# No route matches [POST] "/users/1/edit"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this error when I try to submit a form to edit user details. I'm using Rails 3.2.7. Here's my controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def index
  @users = User.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @users }
  end
end


def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @user }
  end
end

def new
  @user = User.new
end

def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  if @user.save
    sign_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to the app!"
    redirect_to welcome_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    sign_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
     redirect_to welcome_path
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to users_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
end
```

And the form:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <p><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</p>

      <ul>
        <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<div class="box">
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email, class:"input_text" %>
    <br>
  <%= f.label :"edit password" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class:"input_text" %>
    <br>
  <label>
    <br>
  <%= f.submit "Save", class: "button", name: "button" %>
  </label>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Rake routes outputs:

```
         users GET    /users(.:format)              users#index
               POST   /users(.:format)              users#create
      new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)          users#new
     edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)     users#edit
          user GET    /users/:id(.:format)          users#show
               PUT    /users/:id(.:format)          users#update
               DELETE /users/:id(.:format)          users#destroy
```

Let me know if there is something else I should be posting... thanks in advance

Comment: May you post the generated HTML form tag of your edit page?

Comment: <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/8" class="edit_user" id="edit_user_8" method="post">

Answer (score 1):

Edit MUST be a GET, all methods are GET, except CREATE(POST), UPDATE(PUT) and DESTROY(DELETE). Could you copy the HTML code of the form generated by your app?

Comment: <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/8" class="edit_user" id="edit_user_8" method="post"> –

Comment: could you copy all your controller code? what version of rails are you using?

Comment: hi, I added the entire controller to the post. I'm using Rails 3.2.7. Thanks!

Comment: Everything seems fine to me. The code generated for the form it's ok. Try changing welcome_path to @user. The other thing you can do it's upload all your code to github, so we can test the app locally.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your edit_user route be a POST route ? I see here that /users/1/edit is a GET route.
Maybe you have made a mistake in your config/routes.rb ?

Could you post it ?

Comment: Hmm there is nothing in routes.rb that references editing users.. This is the same as in [the sample app by Hartl though](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app/blob/master/config/routes.rb)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by removing:

```
gem 'rails-api'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the same error and I've got that solved using: a explicit format for get and patch:

> get 'edit',id:@user

And:

> patch 'update',id:@user, user: { name:  name,
>                                            email: email,
>                                            password:              "",
>                                            password_confirmation: "" }

Using gems:

- ruby 2.0
- Using rails (4.1.4)
- Using rspec-support 3.4.1
- Using rspec-core 3.4.1
- Using rspec-expectations 3.4.0
- Using rspec-mocks 3.4.0
- Using rspec-rails 3.4.0

*bundle update does not update rspec gems in 3.4.0 to 4.1*